# Error en Join query con paginación para Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-10g

Estoy ejecutando este query en SqlDeveloper apuntando a una base de datos en Oracle 10g:

```
select P1.FIELD1, P1.COD from 
(select P1.FIELD1, P1.COD, row_number() 
over (order by P1.FIELD1) r from 
SCHEMA1.P2 
INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.P1 on SCHEMA1.P1.COD=P2.FIELD2) 
where P1.FIELD_11 = 'VALUE1' and r between 6 and 10;
```

Y Oracle retorna:

```
Error SQL: ORA-00904: "P1"."FIELD_11": invalid identifier
```

Intenté:

```
select SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD1, SCHEMA1.P1.COD from 
(select SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD1, SCHEMA1.P1.COD, row_number() 
over (order by SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD1) r from 
SCHEMA1.P2 
INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.P1 on SCHEMA1.P1.COD=SCHEMA1.P2.FIELD2) 
where SCHEMA1.P1.FIELD_11 = 'VALUE1' and r between 6 and 10;
```

Y obtengo el mismo error:

```
ORA-00904: "SCHEMA1"."P1"."FIELD_11": invalid identifier
```

No puedo encontrar ejemplos de sentencias select con inner join y paginación para Oracle 10g, de modo que no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal es que el `SELECT` "exterior" no puede "ver" las tablas `P1` y `P2` directamente. Lo único que ve son las columnas devueltas por el `SELECT` "interior". Por esta misma razón, tu `SELECT` "exterior" no debería hacer referencia a las columnas con `SCHEMA.P1.xxx`. `SCHEMA.P1` no existe en ese `SELECT`.

Tienes 2 opciones. Escoge la que resulte más adecuado para tu lógica de paginación.

Primera opción: mover la condición dentro del `SELECT` "interior":

```
select FIELD1, COD 
from (
  select P1.FIELD1,
         P1.COD,
         row_number() over (order by P1.FIELD1) r 
    from SCHEMA1.P2 
   inner jin SCHEMA1.P1
      on P1.COD = P2.FIELD2
     and P1.FIELD_11 = 'VALUE1' -- mueve la condición aquí
) 
where r between 6 and 10;
```

Segunda opción: Agregar `FIELD_11` al resultado del `SELECT` "interior":

```
select FIELD1, COD 
from (
  select P1.FIELD1,
         P1.COD,
         P1.FIELD_11, -- agrega esto
         row_number() over (order by P1.FIELD1) r 
    from SCHEMA1.P2 
   inner jin SCHEMA1.P1
      on P1.COD = P2.FIELD2
) 
where FIELD_11 = 'VALUE1'
  and r between 6 and 10;
```